# NaN results in tensorflow Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, nan

I have this problem that after one iteration nearly all my parameters (cost function, weights, hypothesis function, etc.) output 'NaN'. My code is similar to the tensorflow tutorial MNIST-Expert (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html). I looked for solutions already and so far I tried: reducing the learning rate to nearly zero and setting it to zero, using AdamOptimizer instead of gradient descent, using sigmoid function for the hypothesis function in the last layer and using only numpy functions. I have some negative and zero values in my input data, so I can't use the logarithmic cross entropy instead of the quadratic cost function. The result is the same, butMy input data consist of stresses and strains of soils.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import Datafiles3_pv_complete as soil
import numpy as np

m_training = int(18.0)
m_cv = int(5.0)
m_test = int(5.0)
total_examples = 28

" range for running "
range_training = xrange(0,m_training)
range_cv = xrange(m_training,(m_training+m_cv))
range_test = xrange((m_training+m_cv),total_examples)

""" Using interactive Sessions"""
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

""" creating input and output vectors """
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 11])
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])

""" Standard Deviation Calculation"""
stdev = np.divide(2.0,np.sqrt(np.prod(x.get_shape().as_list()[1:])))

""" Weights and Biases """

def weights(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=stdev)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=1.0)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

""" Creating weights and biases for all layers """
theta1 = weights([11,7])
bias1 = bias([1,7])

theta2 = weights([7,7])
bias2 = bias([1,7])

"Last layer"
theta3 = weights([7,3])
bias3 = bias([1,3])


""" Hidden layer input (Sum of weights, activation functions and bias)
z = theta^T * activation + bias
"""
def Z_Layer(activation,theta,bias):
    return tf.add(tf.matmul(activation,theta),bias)

""" Creating the sigmoid function 
sigmoid = 1 / (1 + exp(-z))
"""
def Sigmoid(z):
    return tf.div(tf.constant(1.0),tf.add(tf.constant(1.0), tf.exp(tf.neg(z))))

""" hypothesis functions - predicted output """    
' layer 1 - input layer '
hyp1 = x
' layer 2 '
z2 = Z_Layer(hyp1, theta1, bias1)
hyp2 = Sigmoid(z2)
' layer 3 '
z3 = Z_Layer(hyp2, theta2, bias2)
hyp3 = Sigmoid(z3)
' layer 4 - output layer '
zL = Z_Layer(hyp3, theta3, bias3)
hypL = tf.add( tf.add(tf.pow(zL,3), tf.pow(zL,2) ), zL)


""" Cost function """
cost_function = tf.mul( tf.div(0.5, m_training), tf.pow( tf.sub(hypL, y_true), 2)) 

#cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_true*tf.log(hypL) + (1-y_true)*tf.log(1-hypL))

""" Gradient Descent """
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003).minimize(cost_function)       

"""    Training and Evaluation     """

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(hypL, 1), tf.arg_max(y_true, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

""" Testing - Initialise lists  """
hyp1_test = []
z2_test = []
hyp2_test = []
z3_test = []
hyp3_test = []
zL_test = []
hypL_test = []
cost_function_test =[]
complete_error_test = []
theta1_test = []
theta2_test = []
theta3_test = []
bias1_test = []
bias2_test = []
bias3_test = []
""" -------------------------   """

complete_error_init = tf.abs(tf.reduce_mean(tf.sub(hypL,y_true),1))

training_error=[]
for j in range_training:
    feedj = {x: soil.input_scale[j], y_true: soil.output_scale[j] , keep_prob: 1.0}

    """ -------------------------   """
    'Testing - adding to list'
    z2_init = z2.eval(feed_dict=feedj)
    z2_test.append(z2_init)

    hyp2_init = hyp2.eval(feed_dict=feedj)
    hyp2_test.append(hyp2_init)

    z3_init = z3.eval(feed_dict=feedj)
    z3_test.append(z3_init)

    hyp3_init = hyp3.eval(feed_dict=feedj)
    hyp3_test.append(hyp3_init)

    zL_init = zL.eval(feed_dict=feedj)
    zL_test.append(zL_init)

    hypL_init = hypL.eval(feed_dict=feedj)
    hypL_test.append(hypL_init)

    cost_function_init = cost_function.eval(feed_dict=feedj)
    cost_function_test.append(cost_function_init)

    complete_error = complete_error_init.eval(feed_dict=feedj)
    complete_error_test.append(complete_error)
    print 'number iterations: %g, error (S1, S2, S3): %g, %g, %g' % (j, complete_error[0], complete_error[1], complete_error[2])

    theta1_init = theta1.eval()
    theta1_test.append(theta1_init)

    theta2_init = theta2.eval()
    theta2_test.append(theta2_init)

    theta3_init = theta3.eval()
    theta3_test.append(theta3_init)

    bias1_init = bias1.eval()
    bias1_test.append(bias1_init)

    bias2_init = bias2.eval()
    bias2_test.append(bias2_init)

    bias3_init = bias3.eval()
    bias3_test.append(bias3_init)
    """ -------------------------   """

    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict=feedj)
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g" % (j, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict=feedj)
    training_error.append(1 - train_accuracy)

cv_error=[]    
for k in range_cv:
feedk = {x: soil.input_scale[k], y_true: soil.output_scale[k] , keep_prob: 1.0}
    cv_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict=feedk)
    print("cross-validation accuracy %g" % cv_accuracy)
    cv_error.append(1-cv_accuracy) 

for l in range_test:
    print("test accuracy %g" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: soil.input_matrixs[l], y_true: soil.output_matrixs[l], keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

The last weeks I was working on a Unit-model for this problem, but the same output occurred. I have no idea what to try next. Hope someone can help me.

## Edit:

I checked some parameters in detail again. The hypothesis function (hyp) and activation function (z) for layer 3 and 4 (last layer) have the same entries for each data point, i.e. the same value in each line for one column.

Comment: did you check that your input doesn't contain any NaN values. If the input contains NaN values?? Just try `np.isnan(np.sum(input_array))` If it returns nan then your input might contain NaN values

Comment: I checked it for all 27 examples, but the results was always 'False'. I tested it for the input and the output data.

Comment: Try to reduce stddev of bias initializer to small value, e.g. 0.01. Sometimes that might lead to such behavior.

Comment: I changed it to 0.01, 0.001, and even 0.0. Still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What about the all intermediate values on your graph (e.g. z1, z2)? Where does NaN appear for the first time?

Comment: I've noticed you don't use any mean/sum operation for the cost function. Was it done intentionally?

Comment: 1. z2 looks good still (no NaN and different values in each line); values in z3 and zL don't change for several lines, and in hyp3 and hypL they don't change at all. hyp2 consist only out of 0 and 1, except for one column.
2. After the first iteration, the theta1 and z2 have NaN values in the first 4 columns. hyp2 contains only 1's in the last three columns (the others are NaN). theta2 and theta3 don't contain NaN after the first iteration. Starting with z3, all entries are filled with NaN.
3. I think I only forgot to add sum/mean in this attempt. I changed it, but it makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, no more NaN values. The solution is to **scale** my input and output data. The result (accuracy) is still not good, but at least I get some real values for the parameters. I tried feature scaling before in other attempts (where I probably had some other mistakes as well) and assumed it wouldn't help with my problem either.

Answer (score 1):

1e^-3 is still fairly high, for the classifier you've described. NaN actually means that the weights have tended to infinity, so I would suggest exploring even lower learning rates, around 1e^-7 specifically. If it continues to diverge, multiply your learning rate by 0.1, and repeat until the weights are finite-valued.

Comment: I already tried changing the learning rate. I even used a learning rate of 0, but this still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: 0 most definitely won't work - it means the weight update takes no effect. If extremely minuscule learning rates don't work, around 1e^-10, then I would try randomizing your initialization.

Comment: I tried very tiny learning rates up to 1e-20. I don't quite understand what you mean by 'randomizing your initialization'. I initialise my weights (and biases) randomly, and the order of the different examples in the input and output arrays are random as well.